# Data to be determined later: interior mutability or separate HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap, interior-mutability

I have a `struct`, call it `Book`, which let's say stores data on a book sold by a bookstore. It needs to be referenced at many places in some data structure (e.g. with `Rc`) and so cannot be borrowed mutably in the normal way.  However, it has some attribute, say its price, that needs to be filled in at some time later than initialization, after the object already has outstanding references.

So far I can think of two ways to do this, but they both have disadvantages:

- Interior mutability: give `Book` a field such as  `price: RefCell<Option<i32>>` which is initialized to `RefCell::new(Option::None)` when `Book` is initialized.  Later on, when we determine the price of the book, we can use `borrow_mut` to set `price` to `Some(10)` instead, and from then on we can `borrow` it to retrieve its value.

  My sense is that in general, one wants to avoid interior mutability unless necessary, and it doesn't seem here like it ought to be all that necessary.  This technique is also a little awkward because of the `Option`, which we need because the price won't have a value until later (and setting it to `0` or `-1` in the meantime seems un-Rustlike), but which requires lots of `match`es or `unwrap`s in places where we may be logically certain that the price will have already been filled in.
- Separate table: don't store the price inside `Book` at all, but make a separate data structure to store it, e.g. `price_table: HashMap<Rc<Book>, i32>`.  Have a function which creates and populates this table when prices are determined, and then pass it around by reference (mutably or not) to every function that needs to know or change the prices of books.

  Coming from a C background as I do, the `HashMap` feels like unnecessary overhead both in speed and memory, for data that already has a natural place to live (inside `Book`) and "should" be accessible via a simple pointer chase.  This solution also means I have to clutter up lots of functions with an additional argument that's a reference to `price_table`.

Is one of these two methods generally more idiomatic in Rust, or are there other approaches that avoid the dilemma?  I did see `Once`, but I don't think it's what I want, because I'd still have to know at initialization time how to fill in `price`, and I don't know that.

Of course, in other applications, we may need some other type than `i32` to represent our desired attribute, so I'd like to be able to handle the general case.

Comment: Approaching a problem like yours has to start with requirements. What kinds of operations does your bookstore need to support? Every approach is going to have *some* disadvantages; it's up to you to decide which ones are important.

Comment: @trentcl: Of course it's a toy example, but let's say the bookstore needs to be able to collect up a bunch of books whose prices are not yet determined, then later assign prices to the books, then later still access those prices to decide how much to charge a customer.

Comment: @trentcl: "Every approach is going to have some disadvantages" Yes, of course.  My first question is to what extent either approach has the disadvantage of being non-idiomatic.  As a beginner in the language, I don't yet have a good sense for that, which is why I'm asking experts.  My second question is whether there are other common options I don't know about, whose disadvantages may be less important to me.

Comment: A nitpick: since `Option<i32>` is `Copy`, you can use the more efficient `Cell<Option<i32>>` in preference to `RefCell`, which adds run-time checks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your first approach is optimal for this situation. Since you have outstanding references to some data that you want to write to, you *have to* check the borrowing rules at runtime, so `RefCell` is the way to go.
Inside the `RefCell`, prefer an `Option` or a custom `enum` with variants like `Price::NotSet` and `Price::Set(i32)`. If you are really sure, that all prices are initialized at some point, you could write a method `price()` that calls `unwrap` for you or does an assertion with better debug output in the case your `RefCell` contains a `None`.

I guess that the `HashMap` approach would be fine for this case, but if you wanted to have something that is not `Copy` as your value in there, you could run into the same problem, since there might be outstanding references into the map somewhere.

I agree that the `HashMap` would not be the idiomatic way to go here and still choose your first approach, even with `i32` as the value type.

---

Edit:

As pointed out in the comments (thanks you!), there are two performance considerations for this situation. Firstly, if you **really know**, that the contained price is never zero, you can use `std::num::NonZeroU16` and get the `Option` variant `None` for free (see [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU16.html)).

If you are dealing with a type that is `Copy` (e.g. `i32`), you should consider using `Cell` instead of `RefCell`, because it is lighter. For a more detailed comparison, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276150/13679671

Comment: In addition: If your bookstore *never* gives books away for free, you can use an `Option<std::num::NonZeroU64>` instead of an `Option<u64>`. This will have the same memory layout as a `u64`, making the `Option` free.

Comment: Also note that if price is indeed just an integer (or other Copy type), `Cell` offers essentially zero runtime cost with the same benefits in this case. (LLVM or rustc might optimize it worse than no Cell, but certainly better than RefCell).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more approaches.

1. Use `Rc<RefCell<<Book>>` everywhere, with `price: Option<i32>>` in the struct.
2. Declare a `strict BookId(usize)` and make a `library: HashMap<BookId, Book>`.  Make all your references `BookId` and thus indirectly reference books through them everywhere you need to do so.